# Changing legend position/direction using opts() has no effect

Tags: r, ggplot2

Creating the following plot results in the legend being placed vertically, on the right, rather than on the bottom horizontally as indicated in the call to `opts()`:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10), 
                  grp = rep(letters[1:2],each = 5))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = grp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  opts(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

How do I get the legend in the correct spot?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that that `theme_bw()` is placed after the call to `opts()`, and resets some defaults. Just place `theme_bw()` before `opts()`:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = grp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw() +
  opts(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

**Note**: Since version 0.9.2 `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`:

```
theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

[image]